# XSLT 2.0 : Addition of Time and on-on match

Tags: xml, xslt

First of all, I am using XSLT 2.0 with SAXON-HE 9.5.1.5.

1. Is there any alternative of the following command?

   ```
   <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
   ```
2. In my input XML, there is a field of time which will be coming as HH:MM format. I want to add this and the resultant format will also be in HH:MM format only.

### Input XML

```
    <Root>
     <Detail>
      <Time>24:00</Time>
     <Detail>
     <Detail>
      <Time>59:10</Time>
     <Detail>
     <Detail>
      <Time>4:59</Time>
     <Detail>
     <Detail>
      <Time></Time>
     <Detail>
     <Detail>
     <Detail>
    <Root>
```

Would appreciate of quick help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` is defined in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#built-in-templates-shallow-copy, basically, for a single, unnamed mode you can replace it in XSLT 2 or 1 where you don't do streaming with the identity transformation (see also https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#shallow-copy) template:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

As for formatting a duration computed from the sum of your time values converted to `xs:dayTimeDuration`s in XSLT 2, I think

```
  <xsl:function name="mf:format-duration" as="xs:string">
      <xsl:param name="duration" as="xs:dayTimeDuration"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="concat(format-number(xs:integer(floor($duration div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1H'))), '00'), ':', format-number(minutes-from-duration($duration), '00'))"/>
  </xsl:function>
```

does that.

Online sample at http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/nc4NzPS.

Note that your original input sample had empty `Hours` elements, to treat them some additional spec on how to convert them to a time or duration is needed and needs to be implemented.

Comment: How does the requested `HH:MM` format look if you add `99:59` and `00:06` for instance? I think in your previous question I showed you how to add durations in XSLT 2, if you have a sum you can extract components with the various functions https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#component-extraction-durations and you can format numbers with https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-format-integer and https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-format-number

Comment: To answer your question, it should come as 100:05

Comment: You are such a helpful and kind and above all a true Genius, I must say. Can you guide me on that if "Hours" is coming as blank or even there could be a scenario where "Hours" node can also be removed for some "Employee". Any reference point?

Comment: Find out which default value you want for an empty or missing `Hours` element and then push the original input first through a mode that fills in or adds that default value and then use the already suggested grouping and formatted on the input with the defaults added/filled in, as done in http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/nc4NzPS/1.

Comment: Thanks again @Martin. I will check in my processor and will kepp you updated.

Comment: It went well except one case. Sometimes I receive Hours as "-2:39" which means I will get -ve values as well for Hours. Any clue?

Comment: Try to change the conversion/summing to `<xsl:value-of select="mf:format-duration(sum(current-group()/Hours[normalize-space()]/xs:dayTimeDuration(replace(., '(-)?([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2})', '$1PT$2H$3M'))))"/>`, as done in http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/nc4NzPS/3. If you still have problems then ask a separate question on that isolated problem.

Comment: Can you check the case when only -ve hours will be coming?It is coming as -HH:-MM . you can check the link for the test data ..http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/nc4NzPS/6

Answer (score 2):

To add the time values, I would suggest

```
<xsl:variable name="totalTime"
   select="sum(Detail/Time ! 
                xs:dayTimeDuration(replace(., '(\d+):(\d+)', 'PT$1H$2M')))"/>

<xsl:value-of select="hours-from-duration($totalTime), 
                      format-number(minutes-from-duration($totalTime), '00')"
              separator=":"/>
```

An alternative way to convert the time to a duration is to append ":00", convert to `xs:time`, and subtract `xs:time('00:00:00')`.

As regards `xsl:mode`, if you upgrade to a recent release (9.8 or 9.9), the XSLT 3.0 `xsl:mode` declaration is available in Saxon-HE.