# XSLT - Calculate HH:MM

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a source where I need to add HH:MM formatted values and return format should also be in HH:MM. The point is - I may also receive -ve time value. Below are my example:

The result should show the grouping by employees with hours as HH:MM format.

```
    <Employees>
     <Employee>
            <Amount>#1,424.85</Amount>
            <EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
            <Name>Bob</Name>
            <Surname>Shibob</Surname>
            <Hours>-24:20</Hours>
     </Employee>
     <Employee>
            <Amount>#(1,424.85</Amount>
            <EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
            <Name>Bob</Name>
            <Surname>Shibob</Surname>
            <Hours>-56:00</Hours>
     </Employee>
     <Employee>
            <Amount>#70</Amount>
            <EmployeeID>2</EmployeeID>
            <Name>Sara</Name>
            <Surname>Lee</Surname>
            <Hours>-2:39</Hours>
     </Employee>
    </Employees>
```

Comment: Is this the follow up question from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677413/xslt-2-0-addition-of-time-and-on-on-match? You might want to edit your question to show the XSLT you have tried, and the output you expect. Thank you!

Comment: I have managed it, Thanks!